Сan't get the page with Scrapy
I try to get product page from ideal.de. For example,  https://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/OffersOfProduct/202300102_-replica-on-a-date-eau-de-toilette-30ml-maison-martin-margiela.html
I use scrapy shell like
scrapy shell
'https://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/OffersOfProduct/202300102_-replica-on-a-date-eau-de-toilette-30ml-maison-martin-margiela.html' --set USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36"
As result:
INFO: Spider opened
DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/OffersOfProduct/202300102_-replica-on-a-date-eau-de-toilette-30ml-maison-martin-margiela.html> (failed 1 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/OffersOfProduct/202300102_-replica-on-a-date-eau-de-toilette-30ml-maison-martin-margiela.html took longer than 180.0 seconds..
DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/OffersOfProduct/202300102_-replica-on-a-date-eau-de-toilette-30ml-maison-martin-margiela.html> (failed 2 times): User timeout caused connection failure: Getting https://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/OffersOfProduct/202300102_-replica-on-a-date-eau-de-toilette-30ml-maison-martin-margiela.html took longer than 180.0 seconds..

At the same time scary shell 'https://www.idealo.de' works fine
I would really appreciate any explanation in the subject!

This is expected when a website has antibot protection.
